# String to time conversion in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, typeconverter, time-format

How to convert string to time? This code returns nothing.

```
$id = strtoupper($_POST['id']);
$query = mysql_query("SELECT STR_TO_DATE('RD/OT 07:30','%x %h:%i')  as ScheduleIn  FROM tbl_uploadedschedule") or die(mysql_error());
$res =   mysql_fetch_array($query);
$r = $res['ScheduleIn'];
return($r);
```

Comment: Im sorry sir. I won't do it again.

Comment: Sorry for the disturb Sirs, I now get the exact info i need. I just need to use the MID() to retrieve only the 7:30 in the string "RD/OT 7:30" then use the STR_TO_DATE() to convert to time :)

Comment: I use this for STR_TO_DATE(MID(scheduleIn,7,4), '%h:%i') for "RD/OT 07:30".

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `strtotime()` : http://fr.php.net/manual/fr/function.strtotime.php

Answer (score 0):

You're using [`mysql_fetch_array`](https://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_array), so you'd need to use `$res[0]` as the array resulting from your query won't have a key named ScheduleIn with this function, hence nothing is returned.

Alternatively, use [`mysql_fetch_assoc`](https://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc) and keep `$res['ScheduleIn']`.

Answer (score 0):

do it by [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.strtotime.php). Anyway if you want to use `STR_TO_DATE` you have to correctly specificate format! Both strings have to match their "pattern" (check commas in example)

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('21,5,2013','%d,%m,%Y'); // example
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('07:30','%h:%i') // your case
```